# How to invite people not on your application from Facebook(android sdk)

Tags: android, facebook, social-networking

I was wondering if there was a way to see who is or isn't using your application on Facebook. For example, sets say I have an application X that a user Y has just connected to. I want to find out if Y's friend Z has allowed X or not.

Then, if friend Z has not allowed/used X with Facebook before -- I want to invite that friend to use X.

Is there any way to do this using the GraphAPI and the Facebook-android-sdk?

Thanks in advance,

hwrd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this -- however Facebook Query Language(FQL) needs to be used.

The query is

`SELECT uid FROM user WHERE has_added_app = 1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $user`